# Rotating 'Transform Controls' before resizing in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I'd like to increase the rectangle width (**not** the width of the selected fragment). Is it possible to rotate the 'Transform Control' frame CCW a bit (keeping the fragment untouched) before resizing? If no, how to do such things efficiently?

[image]

Obviously I can rotate the fragment CW, increase the  width then rotate it back (CCW). But I'll never fit the border pixels perfectly this way.

**UPD** I tried to convert the fragment layer into a smart object but don't get how it helps.

[image]

Regards,

Comment: I don't think there is any method to force the bounding box to pixel edges *after* something has been rotated. The bounding box generally only conforms to edges of vector shapes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Photoshop: align transform box with an selection area](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/150752/photoshop-align-transform-box-with-an-selection-area)

Comment: @Wolff, well my question is a bit wider as I suggest at least 1 solution (I don't like it though). If it's impossible in PS, what technique is the most suitable then?

Comment: As I mention in my answer to the other question: use smart objects! Or place, scale and stretch your images in a vector application like Illustrator or InDesign. Both add another layer of complexity as you need to "enter" images and edit them separately from where you put them together. I can't really see another way. You can't have both the ability to rotate and edit pixel layers and at the same time expect Photoshop to somehow remember or guess every layer's initial rotation and scale.

Comment: @Wolff Sorry, I'm still not getting how converting to a smart object helps. I've converted but it looks exactly the same. Just in case: the fragment is a part of a texture (from the hidden background layer), I want its left side be the same to avoid appearing a visible 'border' after resizing.

Comment: Smart Object is a container. Whatever you do to it in the main document is non-destructive and it doesn't actually modify the SO contents in any way, only the way it is shown in the main document. You can edit SO contents by double clicking the layer thumbnail in the layers panel. Or by right-clicking the layer and `Edit contents`. That opens the SO contents in a temp document with the original state of the image(s) intact. If you rotate the SO in the main doc, the original inside the SO doesn't rotate and its transform controls conform to the rectangle as long as you don't rotate that too.

Comment: If we are talking about extending a texture, I would probably just forget about Free transform + SO's and just duplicate the layer and offset it to extend the texture + feather the edges if necessary... and/or use clone stamp tool to help make it seamless. Cause you say it's a texture and it looks like... a texture, so if you stretch that... It's going to look stretched and that's not usually something you'd want to do to a texture, especially if it has to match with something else.

Comment: You need to turn the rectangle into a Smart Object *before* rotating for the transform box. See the gif in my answer to the linked question. I don't think this approach will solve your problem though.

Comment: Your question is stranding here because it's a so-called [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You have some problem you need solved, but you ask specifically for a solution you imagine could work. That question has been asked before and the answer doesn't help you. So now we can't help you with your real problem because that wouldn't be answering the question you ask. You should consider closing this question as a duplicate and then post a new question where you explain the actual problem you have (filling an area with a texture?) and then people can come with solutions.